# Google site search - How to only get autocompletions from a specifed label

Tags: google-search-api

I am using the paid version of Google Site Search. We have various labels used to limit the search to certain parts of our site.

The autocompletions seem to be generated across all labels. I want to only have suggestions from the sites specified by a certain label.

I have tried setting the defaultToRefinement attribute on the  element. I have also tried to use "more:" in the q parameter when calling http://clients1.google.com/complete/search.
But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no support for the paid version?